# What Magento Event fires on 'Reorder'?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

What event fires when the user clicks 'Reorder'? We are making an observer module that will execute after the user clicks 'Reorder' - we want to remove deprecated products from the order and replace them with current products.

[image]

The events I've tried are below and they don't fire when the user clicks reorder:

- sales_order_place_before
- adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer

PS: An alternative solution would be an observer that watches 'Cart Summary' page and lists what products are in the cart. Maybe you know of the event name for this event?

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch following event

```
controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_reorder
```

Answer (score 0):

I think event will be **adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer**